# AWS VPC: Trying to understand how I got all these network ACL rules

Tags: amazon-ec2, acl

Have had a website running on AWS EC2 instances since 2011. Simple configuration using security groups to treat one instance running nginx as a bastion server allowing HTTP and HTTPS access from anywhere, serving static content directly and proxying PHP requests via HTTP to other instances running apache with no public access. I do not believe I have *ever* done *anything* with network ACLs. But just by chance I came across these network ACL inbound rules for my VPC. None of the CIDRs are meaningful to me.

```
100 All traffic All All 114.134.184.0/21     Deny
101 All traffic All All 1.68.0.0/14  Deny
102 All traffic All All 1.80.0.0/13  Deny
103 All traffic All All 1.92.0.0/14  Deny
104 All traffic All All 1.192.0.0/13     Deny
105 All traffic All All 1.202.0.0/15     Deny
106 All traffic All All 1.204.0.0/14     Deny
107 All traffic All All 14.144.0.0/12    Deny
108 All traffic All All 14.208.0.0/12    Deny
109 All traffic All All 23.80.54.0/24    Deny
110 All traffic All All 23.104.141.0/24  Deny
112 All traffic All All 23.226.208.0/24  Deny
113 All traffic All All 27.8.0.0/13  Deny
117 All traffic All All 27.50.128.0/17   Deny
118 All traffic All All 27.54.192.0/18   Deny
119 All traffic All All 27.106.128.0/18  Deny
120 All traffic All All 27.115.0.0/17    Deny
121 All traffic All All 27.148.0.0/14    Deny
32766   All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0    Allow
*   All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0    Deny
```

Is it possible these were present by default when the account and its single VPC were created 10 years ago? Are these CIDRs meaningful to anyone else? I did just create a new free-tier account, and the network ACL for its VPC has only these two sensible sensible rules: allow all from 0.0.0.0/32 followed by deny all for 0.0.0.0/32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to APNIC WHOIS, all of them are exact matches for various network prefixes located in China, so I suspect that was part of your security policy at the time. At the same time it's *very* unlikely to be an Amazon default to block an entire country.

Comment: As far back as I can remember (admittedly not a terribly strong statement these days), my reaction to spammers and scrapers was to use linux iptables, with blocklists from a site on the internet that did indeed aggressively block lots of foreign CIDRs, including, but not limited to, China. But I really don't think I ever touched the VPC network ACLs - I'm not even certain the feature existed in 2011.

Comment: Well, I'm going to accept this answer, as it's the only logical explanation. The fact that I don't remember doing something doesn't mean I didn't do it :-) Looking at my current iptables blocklist for China, nearly every single one of these CIDRs is in that table. Thinking about it a little harder, I can conjure a vague memory of  having a list of CIDRs to block that I did something about before discovering iptables - which is much easier to maintain.than Amazon/s ACLs