# Why can I not communicate through VPC peering connection to VPC in another account?

Tags: networking, routing, amazon-ec2

I have two amazon AWS accounts, a paid one that hosts public webservers (called "**paid**" below), and a free tier account (called "**free**" below). Each has a couple of EC2 instances running Amazon Linux in its own VPC, each with a single subnet with no overlap between them. I wanted to be able to transfer files easily between accounts, including accessing a git bare repository on **paid** from **free**. So I read up on VPC peering connections, and I believe I followed the guides correctly, creating and accepting a peering connection between the VPCs, then modifying security groups, and setting up routes in each VPC to access the subnet in the other VPC.

Here is the basic setup for the **paid** account:

VPC:
[image: paid VPC]

Peering connection and routes:
[image: paid Peering connection and routes]

Security group:
[image: paid security group]

And here is the same information for the **free** account:

VPC:
[image: free VPC]

Peering connection and routes:
[image: free peering connection and routes]

Security group:
[image: free security group]

What I find is that from an instance in the **paid** account, I can successfully ping an instance in the free account:

```
$ ip -f inet addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.12/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ping 172.31.30.44
PING 172.31.30.44 (172.31.30.44) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.30.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.722 ms
```

But I cannot ping from the **free** account to the **paid** account:

```
$ ip -f inet addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.31.30.44/20 brd 172.31.31.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 3259sec preferred_lft 3259sec
$ ping 10.0.0.12
PING 10.0.0.12 (10.0.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.12 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13308ms
```

Can anyone explain why this configuration does not allow me to ping a host in the **paid** account from a host in the **free** account?

Do I need to provide more information (if so, what)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1632909/695037) to an unrelated question about network ACLs on the **paid** account's VPC, I mentioned that I had replaced the use of AWS network ACL's by the linux iptables command. When I set it up ten years ago, I was not expecting to ever want to communicate with any private addresses outside my own subnet. So I was dropping inbound connections from 172.16.0.0/12. So that's why I was able to reach **free** from **paid**, but not the reverse. Removing that iptables block fixes the problem.

How embarrassing!